# Cookie parser's "res.cookie('cookieName', {cookieData}); doesn't set a cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I'm working on with **nodeJs**, and **ExpressJs**.

recently, I had this issue :

> after **res.cookie('cookieName', {cookieValue});** my **req.cookies** is still empty.

Here is my code [when I set the cookie]

```
res
      .cookie('vendor', vendor,
        {
          expires: moment().add(CONF.server.tokens.expiration.short, 'h').toDate(),
          httpOnly: false,
        });
```

And here is my code [when i want to get this cookie]

```
 await request({
    method: 'POST',
    baseUrl: process.env.SERVER,
    uri: '/users/shops/' + req.cookies.vendor.vendorId + '/credits',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.cookies.access_token,
      'User-Agent': req.get('User-Agent'),
      'X-Forwarded-For': req.ip
    },
    json: true,
    body: {
      packs: req.body.packs,
      stripeToken: req.body.stripeToken
    }
  });
```

> When I use Visual studio code's debugger, here is what i got, an empty object :
>   [debugger screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxNql.png)

Thanks a lot for your precious help, have a nice day/night.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change "httponly=true" and send your response through res.send()